# Where does many produce the empty string?

Tags: regex, parsing, haskell

I am currently reading Programming in Haskell by Graham Hutton. I am stuck on the chapter of Parsers. In it there are two mutually recursive functions defined as:

```
many  p = many1 p +++ return []
many1 p = do v  <- p
             vs <- many p   
             return (v:vs)
```

Where `many` is actually transformed into this form:

```
many1 p = p >>= (\ v -> many p >>= (\ vs -> return (v : vs)))
```

The `>>=` operator is defined as:

```
p >>= f =  P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                           []        -> []
                           [(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out)
```

The `+++` operator is defined as:

```
p +++ q =  P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                           []        -> parse q inp
                           [(v,out)] -> [(v,out)])
```

The other functions relevant to this question are these:

```
parse             :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse (P p) inp   =  p inp

sat p =  do x <- item
            if p x then return x else failure

digit =  sat isDigit

failure = P (\inp -> [])
item    = P (\inp -> case inp of
                          []     -> []
                          (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)])
return v = P (\inp -> [(v,inp)])
```

Now, when attempting to use `many1` to parse digits from the string `"a"`, like:

```
parse (many digit) "a"
```

the result is `[("","a")]`.

When attempting to parse digits from the string `"a"` using `many1` like:

```
parse (many1 digit) "a"
```

the result is `[]`.

I think I understand why the second result. `(many1 digit)` attempts to parse the string `"a"`, and so it calls `digit "a"` which fails since `"a"` is not a digit, and so the empty list is returned `[]`.

However, I do not understand the first result when using `(many digit)`. If `(many1 digit)` returns `[]` then obviously it failed, and so in the `+++` operator, the second case expression is executed. But when I try to `parse (return []) "a"` the result I get back is `[([], "a")]`.

I don't get it why the result of `many` is `[("", "a")]`, when the result of `many1` is `[]`.
Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080997/unable-to-understand-a-mutual-recursion) already, but it doesn't give me the answer I am looking for.

Comment: When you talk about "manny" and "manny1" is that just a mis-spelling of "many" or do you mean something different?

Comment: Bear in mind that "" == [] because literal strings are just synactic sugar for lists of characters. Hence [([], "a")] == [("", "a")]

Comment: It's pretty easy: `many` means parse *zero* or more occurrences of a given item. The string `"a"` starts with zero digits hence the `""` at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your confusion is that you get back `[("", "a")]` when you expected `[([], "a")]`:

A string is a list of Chars. So `""` is an empty list of Chars. Since `[]` is an empty list of any type, that means that `""` is just a special case of `[]`. In other words `[] :: [Char]` is completely equivalent to `""`.

So since your parser is expected to produce a string, the empty list is known to be of type `[Char]` and thus printed as `""` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Thank you! That is it! So, it's just something the compiler interprets based on the type? right? I just tried 

:{
*| let test :: Parser String
*|     test = (failure +++ return [])
*| :}
*> parse (test) "a"
[("","a")]

And I get back the expected result.